# Finding the max value between the last 22 months or between any 10 hour window within the last 22 months in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to find the max value within the last 22 months OR the max value within any 10 hour window of those last 22 months.

I'm doing this in Microsoft SQL Server.

Essentially, I'm looking to retrieve a value that has sustained a high for at least 10 hours before I consider it my max and if it is larger than the max of the last 22 months, it would be the new max, otherwise I would use the max of the last 22 months.

Here's what I think it should look like pseudo code:

```
   if (time > 10 hours) AND (value = max) OR (18 > time > 0) AND (value = max)

   then output = value
```

The SQL code that I've tried:

```
SELECT TOP 90 PERCENT
    DATEADD(s,time,'19700101') as time_22month
    ,GETDATE() as date_22month
    ,b.tagname as tag_22month
    ,value as value_22month
    ,maximum as max_22month
FROM
    db..hour a
INNER JOIN 
    db..tag b
ON
    a.tagid = b.tagid
WHERE 
    b.tagname like '%T500.1234%' 
AND
    (GETDATE() - DATEADD(s, time, '19700101') < 670) 
ORDER BY
    max_22month DESC 

SELECT 
    DATEADD(s,time,'19700101') as time_10hour
    ,GETDATE() as date_10hour
    ,b.tagname as tag_10hour
    ,value as value_10hour
    ,maximum as max_10hour
FROM
    db..hour a
INNER JOIN 
    db..tag b
ON
    a.tagid = b.tagid
WHERE 
    b.tagname like '%T500.1234%' 
AND
    (GETDATE() - DATEADD(s, time, '19700101') < 0.42) 
ORDER BY
    max_10hour DESC
```

Output right now is the following:

```
+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
|      time_22month       |        date_22month        | tag_22month | value_22month  |  max_22month  |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| 2016-03-08 06:00:00.000 | 2017-04-10 10:07:57:32.783 | T500.1234   |  1567.88546416 | 2445.56419848 |
| 2016-03-08 07:00:00.000 | 2017-04-10 10:07:57:32.783 | T500.1234   |  1499.88546416 | 2434.47673719 |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+

+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|       time_10hour       |        date_10hour         | tag_10hour | value_10hour  |  max_10hour   |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2017-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 2017-04-10 10:07:57:32.783 | T500.1234  | 8763.42572454 | 8759.64548912 |
| 2017-04-10 01:00:00.000 | 2017-04-10 10:07:57:32.783 | T500.1234  | 8001.64578943 | 8001.64578943 |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

So I'm a little confused on how I should be comparing these max values, especially when the 10 hour window needs to be rolling (incrementing every hour). Any help is appreciated.

The output should be the greater value of the two parameters, so perhaps a new table column would be the output along with two columns that precede it that show the highest 22month value and the highest 10 hour window value.

```
+--------+-------------+------------+------+
| Month  | 22Month_Max | 10Hour_Max | Max  |  
+--------+-------------+------------+------+
| July   |        5478 |       5999 | 5999 |
| August |        4991 |       3523 | 4991 |
+--------+-------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What does your query do? How does it differ from expected results? Please provide some sample data and what the query should produce.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: So we've got the current results. I'm still unclear on the *expected results*. Some *sample data* to accompany these would also help (i.e. sample data that represents an input such that, if we get the query right, it shows the results you present to us as the expected results). Also - not clear on `especially when the 10 hour window needs to be rolling (incrementing every hour)` - are you saying that the 10 hour windows have to start/end at an hour with 0 minutes, seconds, millis, etc?

Comment: Alright, sorry about that, I have included a theortetical output. 
What I mean about the 10 hour window is that, every 10 hours, we would like to see the max value, as this strips away outliers outside this window. So if there exists a 10 hour window max that is greater than another 10 hour window in the previous 22 months, then that is the maximum value that we want as an output.